# Please help about Codeigniter, about sales input

Tags: php, codeigniter

this models M_penjualan.php

```
function simpan_penjualan($nofak,$total,$jml_uang,$kembalian){
 $idadmin=$this->session->userdata('idadmin');
 $this->db->query("INSERT INTO tbl_jual (jual_nofak,jual_total,jual_jml_uang,jual_kembalian,jual_user_id,jual_keterangan) VALUES ('$nofak','$total','$jml_uang','$kembalian','$idadmin','eceran')");
        foreach ($this->cart->contents() as $item) {
            $data=array(
                'd_jual_nofak'          =>  $nofak,
                'd_jual_barang_id'      =>  $item['id'],
                'd_jual_barang_nama'    =>  $item['name'],
                'd_jual_barang_satuan'  =>  $item['satuan'],
                'd_jual_barang_harpok'  =>  $item['harpok'],
                'd_jual_barang_harjul'  =>  $item['amount'],
                'd_jual_qty'            =>  $item['qty'],
                'd_jual_diskon'         =>  $item['disc'],
                'd_jual_total'          =>  $item['subtotal']
            );
            $this->db->insert('tbl_detail_jual',$data);
            $this->db->query("update tbl_barang set barang_stok=barang_stok-'$item[qty]' where barang_id='$item[id]'");
        }
        return true;
```

this class CI_Controller Penjualan.php

```
function add_to_cart(){
    if($this->session->userdata('akses')=='1' || $this->session->userdata('akses')=='2'){
        $kobar=$this->input->post('kode_brg');
        $produk=$this->m_barang->get_barang($kobar);
        $i=$produk->row_array();
        $data = array(
               'id'       => $i['barang_id'],
               'name'     => $i['barang_nama'],
               'satuan'   => $i['barang_satuan'],
               'harpok'   => $i['barang_harpok'],
               'price'    => str_replace(",", "", $this->input->post('harjul'))-$this->input->post('diskon'),
               'disc'     => $this->input->post('diskon'),
               'qty'      => $this->input->post('qty'),
               'amount'   => str_replace(",", "", $this->input->post('harjul'))
            );
    if(!empty($this->cart->total_items())){
        foreach ($this->cart->contents() as $items){
            $id=$items['id'];
            $qtylama=$items['qty'];
            $rowid=$items['rowid'];
            $kobar=$this->input->post('kode_brg');
            $qty=$this->input->post('qty');
            if($id==$kobar){
                $up=array(
                    'rowid'=> $rowid,
                    'qty'=>$qtylama+$qty
                    );
                $this->cart->update($up);
            }else{
                $this->cart->insert($data);
            }
        }
    }else{
        $this->cart->insert($data);
    }
```

the latter view v_penjualan.php

```
<?php $i = 1;?>
<?php foreach ($this->cart->contents() as $items): ?>
<?php echo form_hidden($i.'[rowid]', $items['rowid']); ?>
<tr>
<td><?=$items['id'];?></td>
<td><?=$items['name'];?></td>
<td><?=$items['satuan'];?></td>
<td><?php echo number_format($items['amount']);?></td>
<td><?php echo number_format($items['disc']);?></td>
<td><?php echo number_format($items['qty']);?></td>
<td><?php echo number_format($items['subtotal']);?></td>
<td class="text-center"><a href="<?php echo base_url().'admin/penjualan/remove/'.$items['rowid'];?>" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs"><span class="far fa-trash-alt mr-2"></span> Hapus</a></td>
</tr>

<?php $i++; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

in the above code when inputting and leads to add_cart "$rowid=$items['rowid'];" which is displayed Only 6 Rows, I can't add to the 7th input and so on, please help, is there any missing code? thanks for the help.
[image: Just 6 file can't add again]